# What is the process for finding the inverse of a function defined by an integral?

Tags: calculus

I was curious as to if a hunch I had was right, and after doing some research it seems it is, but I don't see enough information to prove it. For a given complicated or special function that is defined as an integral, like the arctangent function, the gamma function, the error function, or just the logarithm function or any other function defined in a similar way, what's the process for finding an explicit inverse of that function? The inverse can also be in integral form, but all I really know for sure is it has something to do with the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)

Also how do I type math equations here? I don't see any latex.

Comment: [This link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) takes you to a quick summary of math formatting on math.SE.

Comment: For information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll keep that in mind.